# Using local firebase database, possible corruption

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, thread-safety, corruption

I need to use a Firebase database, to do this I store a copy of the snapshot, retrieved using `onDataChange()` function of a listener, inside a global variable.

While I'm using the global copy, if a change happens in the Firebase database from another device, won't the global copy be changed whilst I'm using it and thus corrupting it? If so is there a known solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of a DataSnapshot object will never change.  They are immutable.

If you reassign a global variable with a new snapshot, obviously the global variable will change.  But as long as you are working with the snapshot through a local variable, the code that works with the local variable will not see the update.

Comment: So lets say I want to retrieve 3 variables from the database and i have a global copy of a datasnapshot. If after I have retrieved 2 variables another device changes the database variables meaning the global variable would be set in the onDataChanged() function: would this result in the last variable being the newer version? If so is there a way to prevent this so that I can get all the older versions before the global variable is changed?

Comment: I'm not clear what you're asking now.  Please post a new question along with the code that isn't working the way you expect.  It sounds like your question is more about how programming languages work, not how Firebase works.  As I said, snapshots are immutable, and that's all you really need to know about the Firebase SDK when it comes to variables changing over time.  If you need to remember old snapshots, you will need a place to store them.

Comment: I'm sorry for repeating myself, I got a little confused with your answer but I think I get it now. Thank you for your help! ^^